# Is there an instant win condition by abusing a loophole in Bang?

Tags: bang

I apologize for not using the exact names of the cards as I did not play the English version of the game.

In a gaming session with some friends the following situation arose:

- A player had the character which allows to draw a new card when he remains with no cards.
- We were playing with the expansion pack which contained random effects whenever a stagecoach was activated. The special effect in this round was "every card can be used as a Bang card, and Bang cards can be used as missed"
- That player acquired a volcanic pistol, allowing the use of unlimited bang cards in a round.

Isn't that an instant win, by being able to eliminate all players, one by one? If not, what rule did we miss?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The cards in question are: [Showdown](http://www.emilianosciarra.net/en/bang/expansions-bang/wild-west-show/cards)

> **Showdown** - All cards may be played as they were BANG!. BANG! cards may be played as they were Missed!.

The designer notes what the card should read.

> **Actually, the correct text should be that BANG! card must be played as Missed!, otherwise Suzy Lafayette armed with a Volcanic could shoot the whole deck!**

and the cards [Volcanic](http://www.emilianosciarra.net/en/bang/bang/playing-cards) and [Suzy Lafayette](http://www.emilianosciarra.net/en/bang/bang/characters)

> **Volcanic** - (Weapon) Max distance: 1. You may play as many BANG! cards as you wish.
>
> **Suzy Lafayette** - As soon as she remains with no cards in her hand, she draws a card from the deck.

This response differs from the [publisher](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/5569204#5569204)'s answer, or lack there of:

> Q: Shootout. There are questions about how this interacts with player abilities: Calamity Janet ... Willy the Kid..... Suzy Lafayette. If she has a Volcanic card during a Shootout, she can keep drawing new cards and using them as Bang!s until she kills all the other players, if she wants. Should there be some way to limit these situations??
>
> A: About your questions: please consider that unpredictability is a BANG! feature and it is part of his style. We want BANG! to be characterized by two sides: strategy (bluff) and luck. Characters in Wild West Show are powerful, and sometimes the interactions between two of them can be "lethal" for the opponents, but we think this "chance component" is what makes this expansion so crazy and exhilarating! Have fun with BANG!

Comment: The publisher's response sounds like they just didn't carefully check the rules, and assumed that the question was correct about the shoot everyone scenario.

Comment: I think that while this issue is resolved, the publisher's answer says clearly that situations may arise that "break" the game, with some many possible combinations.

Comment: @jsbueno I disagree with your assessment of their answer. I think they meant it as "Look, some combinations of cards will allow one player to completely take out another player." Not "Look, some combinations of cards will allow one player to win the game in a single turn." I just don't think they realized 'broken' aspect of it. The person that answered was probably a customer service rep, not someone who actually understands non-poker-deck card games.

Comment: @jsbueno, I would take the designers word over the publisher.

Comment: I'd say this combination (player is Suzy, has a Volcanic and Showdown is active) is rare enough that in our group, we'd let it go just for laughs. If someone was specifically aiming to get this combination, then we would weaken it, either by adding the Bang -> Missed constraint, or tweaking the character selection process (e.g. by eliminating any choice the player has)

Comment: I'm struggling to follow if three listed scenario changes due to your clarification...?